# deploying django on the pythonanywhere

Tags: wsgi

I want to deploy my personal blog on the pythonanywhere, but there're something wrong with my configuration and I am unfamiliar with severer.But everything goes smoothly on my local server.Then I checked the error file, the detail is following:
[image: error.log]

Besides, pagedown module is used in the view.py, which is one of the part of the markdown in my project:
[image]

Finally, I think there must be something with wsgi.py, this is the wsgi.py, maybe I miss some configurations of my project:[image]

Hope someone solve my problem, can't appreciate too much!

Comment: Have you installed the `django-pagedown` package on PythonAnywhere?  It's not installed by default.  [Instructions on how to install stuff on PythonAnywhere are here](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/InstallingNewModules).

Comment: I tried it, but it does not work, maybe it has something to do with my virtualenv? I created one by pycharm, should I upload my virtualenv directory in pythonanywhere and make a link with it? Besides, does it mean I needn't use pip intall any packages if I set a link between my project and virtualenv?

Comment: Virtualenvs can't be copied from machine to machine -- they often include installation-specific stuff.  What people normally do is keep a file called `requirements.txt` alongside their code (eg. in the same git repository).  That file contains all of your dependencies, one per line.   `pip freeze` from a command shell on your local machine, inside the virtualenv, will generate the appropriate contents, and then on PythonAnywhere (also inside the virtualenv) you'd use `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install them all

Comment: Love u, Giles, it does work after I create a new virtualenve, thank you very much. Besides, do you have some readings about virtualenve, not too difficult, my english is not good.

Comment: The [Django Girls tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org) goes through a deployment using virtualenvs, and is an excellent tutorial whether you're old or young, male or female.  Definitely recommended.  There are translations too -- maybe one of them is for your language?